# regex pattern needed to get data from html source

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm reading html source of an online shop and I can find below information which shows stock availability for each SKU.

```
'{"sku-SV023435_B_M":8,"sku-SV023435_BL_M":10,"sku-SV023435_PU_M":11}'
```

I need to retrieve each SKU and it's quantity in an array.

Please help me which the PHP code.

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the source link
[Source](http://www.dresslink.com/women-round-neck-sleeveless-backless-padded-stretch-solid-short-fitness-sports-bra-tank-tops-p-24984.html)

Comment: This is JSON, use `json_decode`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: But this is a part of an html source, we need some regex to get this part first! @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: write that html in your question too..

Comment: Added already @PHPWorm...

Comment: The JSON substring is probably inside a javascript part, isn't it? So first extract the script string with DOMDocument, then you have the choice: use a third party tokenizer or build a  pattern to find JSON parts that begins with `"sku-` in your javascript code.

Comment: Is it possible give me the code as I'm a beginner! @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
$a = '{"sku-SV023435_B_M":8,"sku-SV023435_BL_M":10,"sku-SV023435_PU_M":11}';
$a = json_decode($a)
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a)
```